# Pyspark: writing results of UDF iteratively back to dataframe does not produce expected results

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I'm still a novice at pyspark and I'm trying to evaluate a function and create columns iteratively with help of a UDF. Following is the function:

```python
def get_temp(df):
    l=['temp1','temp2','temp3']
    s=[0]
    pt = [0]
    start = [0]
    end = [0]
    cummulative_stat = [0]
    for p in xrange(1,4):
        def func(p):
            if p==1:
                pass
            elif p >1:
                start[0] = end[0]
                s[0]=2
                pt[0] =4
            end[0] = start[0] + pt[0] - s[0]
            return end[0]
        func_udf=udf(func,IntegerType())
        df=df.withColumn(l[p-1],func_udf(lit(p)))
    return df
df=get_temp(df)
df.show()
```

The above yields the result:

```python
+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  a|  b|  c|temp1|temp2|temp3|
+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  2| 12|  5|    0|    2|    2|
|  8|  5|  7|    0|    4|    4|
|  9|  4|  3|    0|    2|    2|
|  3|  8|  2|    0|    4|    4|
+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

The expected result is :

```python
+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  a|  b|  c|temp1|temp2|temp3|
+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  2| 12|  5|    0|    2|    4|
|  8|  5|  7|    0|    2|    4|
|  9|  4|  3|    0|    2|    4|
|  3|  8|  2|    0|    2|    4|
+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

If I look the output of inner function alone, the result is as expected i.e.,:

```python
s=[0]
pt = [0]
start = [0]
end = [0]
cummulative_stat = [0]
for p in xrange(1,4):
    def func():
        if p==1:
            pass
        elif p >1:
            start[0] = end[0]
            s[0]=2
            pt[0] =4
        end[0] = start[0] + pt[0] - s[0]
        return end[0]
    e=func()
    print e

output:
0
2
4
```

Not sure what is the right way to write back these results from UDF to df. The dataframe posted is just a sample dataframe, i'll need to use for loop because in my original code I call other functions( who's output depends on iterator's value) within the for loop.For example refer below:

```python
def get_temp(df):
    l=['temp1','temp2','temp3']
    s=[0]
    pt = [0]
    start = [0]
    end = [0]
    q=[]
    cummulative_stat = [0]
    for p in xrange(1,4):
        def func(p):
            if p < a:
                cummulative_stat[0]=cummulative_stat[0]+52
                pass
            elif p >=a:

                if p==1:
                    pass
                elif p >1:
                    start[0] = end[0]
                    s[0]=2
                    pt[0] =4
                if cummulative_stat and p >1:
                    var1=func2(p,3000)
                    var2=func3(var1)
                    cummulative_stat=np.nan
                else:
                    var1=func2(p,3000)
                    var2=func3(var1)         
                end[0] = start[0] + pt[0] - s[0]
            q.append(end[0],var1,var2)
            return q
        func_udf=udf(func,ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType())))
        df=df.withColumn(l[p-1],func_udf(lit(p)))
    return df
df=get_temp(df)
df.show()
```

I'm using pyspark 2.2. Any help is much appreciated.
To create this dataframe:

```python
rdd =  sc.parallelize([(2,12,5),(8,5,7),
                 (9,4,3),
                  (3,8,2)])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ('a', 'b','c'))
df.show()
```

Comment: why do you want to use udf for?

Comment: Could this be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What are you trying to do? There's likely an easier approach.

Comment: @pault i updated the question with the sample code.I wanna use udf because i do make other function calls within it and ultimately do some math on called functions and return an output. The above shown function: func does the math on other function calls

Comment: since your functions are different for different columns I would suggest you to write different functions for each columns and call them separately .

Comment: Could you please shed some more light on this? Not sure how i would decouple into separate functions since the cummulative_stat gets evaluated based on its value obtained in the previous iteration. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have understood looking at your codes is that **your next column value depends on the previous one**. If my understanding is correct then I can tell that *your udf function definition is placed at wrong place*. And *you need minor changes in your codes* to make it work.

Lets go step by step

You already have

```
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  2| 12|  5|
|  8|  5|  7|
|  9|  4|  3|
|  3|  8|  2|
+---+---+---+
```

We need *a initializer column and I see that it is 0*

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

df=df.withColumn('temp0', F.lit(0))
```

which should be

```
+---+---+---+-----+
|  a|  b|  c|temp0|
+---+---+---+-----+
|  2| 12|  5|    0|
|  8|  5|  7|    0|
|  9|  4|  3|    0|
|  3|  8|  2|    0|
+---+---+---+-----+
```

We should *move the `udf` function outside of the loop* as

```
def func(p, end):
    start = 0
    s = 0
    pt = 0
    if p==1:
        pass
    elif p >1:
        start = end
        s=2
        pt =4
    end = start + pt - s
    return end

func_udf=F.udf(func, T.IntegerType())
```

and *call the `udf` function within the loop* as

```
def get_temp(df):
    l=['temp1','temp2','temp3']
    for p in xrange(1,4):
        df=df.withColumn(l[p-1],func_udf(F.lit(p), F.col('temp'+str(p-1))))
    return df

df=get_temp(df)
```

and finally *drop the initializer column*

```
df=df.drop('temp0')
```

which should give you your desired output

```
+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  a|  b|  c|temp1|temp2|temp3|
+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  2| 12|  5|    0|    2|    4|
|  8|  5|  7|    0|    2|    4|
|  9|  4|  3|    0|    2|    4|
|  3|  8|  2|    0|    2|    4|
+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful